# Access to parent records in nested MySQL Queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a problem with MySQL nested queries. First i want get all products, then in a nested query, iterate over all products (each product is a JSON) and for each product get their images adding a key 'images' to the current product.

```
exports.findAll = function(callback) {
  var Database = require('../config/database.js')
  var DBConnection = new Database()
  var connection = DBConnection.connect()

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM product', function(err, records, fields) {
    var products = records
    for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
      connection.query('SELECT Image FROM product_images WHERE Product = ?', [products[i].Id],
        function(err, images, fields) {
          console.log(products[i])
        })
    }
    DBConnection.disconnect()
    callback(err, products)
  })
}
```

In the nested query, products[i] is undefined and can't add the images. ¿How can i solve this?

If a first get the records in the route, and then get the images calling to another function passing the records getted and iterate over they, maybe works, but i wanna know if exists a more 'easy' way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved iterating only with for each:

```
exports.findAll = function(callback) {
  var Database = require('../config/database.js')
  var DBConnection = new Database()
  var connection = DBConnection.connect()
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM product'

  connection.query(query, function(err, products) {
    products.forEach(function(cur) {
      var query = 'SELECT Image FROM product_images WHERE Product = ?'
      connection.query(query, [cur['Id']], function(err, images) {
        cur['images'] = images
        callback(err, products)
      })
    })
    DBConnection.disconnect()
  })
}
```

Can someone explain me why works with forEach and don't with normal for or for in?